# Get the value from an object when you don't know the keys

Tags: javascript

I am passed an object lets say called **myobj**.

```
Key: last, Value: "Yellow"
```

To get the key it is

```
Object.keys(myobj) // = ["last"]
```

To get the value it is

```
myobj.last // = "Yellow"
```

But I want to handle any key.
So in pseudo code I want to combine these.

```
myobj.Object.keys(myobj)  // to return "Yellow" or whatever the incoming key of the object is.
```

Comment: Related: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access object property

```js
var myobj = {
  last: "yellow"
};

var res = myobj[Object.keys(myobj)[0]];

document.write(res);
```

Comment: This relies on knowing that the key is at zero index. For a more complex object with several properties how do you do it?

Comment: Use for loop and iterate over the key array ( or use forEach iterator ) and get property based on key